# R maximum distance of a matrix after removing some of values

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix like below,

```
A <- matrix(c(1,7,13,19,9,5,8,14,20,10,3,4,15,21,1,2,4,16,22,2,8,3,17,23,1,6,3,18,24,2), nrow=5)
```

```
 A
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
 [1,]    1      5      3      2      8      6
 [2,]    7      8      4      4      3     3
 [3,]    13     14     15     16     17     18
 [4,]    19     20     21     22     23     24
 [5,]    9      10     1      2      1      2
```

The `dist` function can calculate the **maximum absolute** distance between each row of the matrix `A` and return distance matrix `D` using `dist(A, method = "maximum")`. `D[i,j] = \max_{k}(|A[i,k]-A[j,k]|)`          For example,

```
 D[1,2] = max( abs( A[1,] - A[2,] ) ) = max(6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3) = 6
```

However, in my case,  I need to firstly remove the `i, j` element , i.e, `D[i,j] = \max_{k not equal to i or j}(|A[i,k]-A[j,k]|)`, for example, in the above example, the answer beomes

```
 D[1,2] = max( abs( A[1,] - A[2,] ) ) = max( 1, 2, 5, 3) = 5
```

I have no idea how to do this in a efficient way, I know I can use for loop, but the data set is large, for loop is extremely slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your real matrix also has columns more than rows. Here is a base R implementation of the function you want:

```
max_dist <- function(mat, i, j) {
  mat <- mat[c(i, j), -c(i, j)]
  max(abs(mat[1L, ] - mat[2L, ]))
}

dist1 <- function(mat) {
  n <- nrow(mat)
  ids <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:n, function(i, e) cbind(i:e, rep.int(i - 1L, e - i + 1L)), n))
  out <- apply(ids, 1L, function(i) max_dist(mat, i[[1L]], i[[2L]]))
  attributes(out) <- list(
    Size = n, Labels = dimnames(mat)[[1L]], Diag = FALSE, 
    Upper = FALSE, method = "dist1", call = match.call(), 
    class = "dist"
  )
  out
}
```

If you think R is not fast enough for your case, then you can use the package `parallelDist`, which allows user-defined C++ distance functions. Consider the following implementation:

```
library(parallelDist)
library(RcppXPtrUtils)
library(RcppArmadillo)

mydist_ptr <- cppXPtr("double mydist(const arma::mat &A, const arma::mat &B) {
  arma::uvec ids = {0, (unsigned int)A(0, 0), (unsigned int)B(0, 0)};
  arma::mat A_ = A, B_ = B;
  A_.shed_cols(ids); B_.shed_cols(ids); 
  return abs((A_ - B_)).max();
}", depends = "RcppArmadillo")

dist2 <- function(mat) {
  # prepend row numbers to the matrix
  # this later allows cpp function `mydist` to identify which rows to drop 
  parDist(cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), mat), method = "custom", func = mydist_ptr) 
}
```

Test with the following matrices (`small_m` is the example in your post):

```
small_m <- matrix(c(1,5,3,2,8,6,7,8,4,4,3,3,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,9,10,1,2,1,2), 5, 6, byrow = TRUE)
large_m <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), 10, 100000)
```

Benchmark

```
# no real difference between these two implementations when the input matrix is small
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(dist1(small_m), dist2(small_m))
Unit: microseconds
           expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval cld
 dist1(small_m)  77.4  87.10 112.403  106.5 125.95 212.2   100  a 
 dist2(small_m) 145.5 160.25 177.786  170.2 183.80 286.7   100   b

# `dist2` is faster with large matrix input. However, the efficiency of `dist1` is also acceptable IMO.
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(dist1(large_m), dist2(large_m))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 dist1(large_m) 129.7531 139.3909 152.13154 143.0549 149.5870 322.0173   100   b
 dist2(large_m)  48.8025  52.5081  55.84333  55.5175  58.6095  67.6470   100  a
```

Output as follows

```
> dist1(small_m)
   1  2  3  4
2  5         
3 14 15      
4 18 21  6   
5  5  3 16 22
> dist2(small_m)
   1  2  3  4
2  5         
3 14 15      
4 18 21  6   
5  5  3 16 22
```

Comment: what if the  number of columns equals to the number of rows.

Comment: @kevin as far as I can tell, this is still OK. The real problem is when you have, for example, 6 rows with 5 columns. As there is no column 6 for you to drop, you will get some errors like "subscript out of range".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `dist` + `combn` + `as.dist`

```
r <- diag(0,nrow(m))
r[lower.tri(r)] <- combn(1:nrow(m),2,function(k) max(abs(do.call(`-`,asplit(m[k,],1)))[-k]))
out <- as.dist(r)
```

which gives

```
   1  2  3  4
2  5
3 14 15
4 18 21  6
5  5  3 16 22
```

**Data**

```
> dput(m)
structure(c(1, 7, 13, 19, 9, 5, 8, 14, 20, 10, 3, 4, 15, 21, 
1, 2, 4, 16, 22, 2, 8, 3, 17, 23, 1, 6, 3, 18, 24, 2), .Dim = 5:6)
```